# How to extend dijit/ColorPalette with custom color (particular with transparent)

Tags: dojo, color-palette

I use standard *digit ColorPalette* in my widget. It is simple tool and it works fine.

But I need to expand it with *transparent* or *none* color. I can deal with it in few ways:

1. Add just a button near the Palette to clear the color
2. Copy all code from `dijit/ColorPalette` to make custom Palette in my module
3. **Extend** the `dijit/ColorPalette` in my module only by one `none` color *(preferable way)*

Please point me how to extend `dijit/ColorPalette` or another way to implement `<set_none_color>` action if simple extending is imposible.

*I'm newbie in Dojo and i want to deal with it in right way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by extending `dijit/ColorPalette` *(make subclass)*. I added basic functionality that I want.
In general I did following:

1. override template to add holder for new element
2. add slider which controls alpha component
3. override `onChange` to blend *color & alpha* channels and return CSS value of color,
   also add `onChangeCss` to monitor changes in my module.

The code is quite simple and efficient *(this is basic example which can be improved)*

```
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/ColorPalette", "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
     "dojo/_base/Color" ], function(declare,
    ColorPalette, HorizontalSlider, Color) {
return declare([ ColorPalette ], {
    //add some fields
    valueCss:'none',
    valueRgb:null,
    valueA:0,
    //override template
    templateString:'<div class="dijitInline dijitColorPalette" role="grid">'+
                        '<table><tr><td><span>Alpha</span></td>'+
                            ' <td><div data-dojo-attach-point="aSlider">  </div></td></tr></table>'+
                        '<table dojoAttachPoint="paletteTableNode" class="dijitPaletteTable" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" role="presentation">'+
                            '<tbody data-dojo-attach-point="gridNode"> '+
                            '</tbody></table>'+
                    '</div>',

    postCreate: function(){
        //closure this
        var obj = this;
        this.value='#000000';
        //add slider
        this.alpha = new HorizontalSlider({
            name: "alpha",
            value: 0,
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 5,
            discreteValues:6,
            intermediateChanges: true,
            style: "width:150px;",
            onChange: function(value){
                obj.valueA = this.value / this.maximum;
                obj.onChange(null);
            }
        }).placeAt(this.aSlider);

    },
    //override onChange to blend color & alpha and return CSS value 
    onChange: function(value){
        this.valueRgb = Color.fromHex(this.value);
        this.valueCss = Color.fromArray([this.valueRgb.r,this.valueRgb.g,this.valueRgb.b,this.valueA]).toCss(true);
        this.onChangeCss(this.valueA ? this.valueCss : 'transparent');
    },
    //use this method instead of onChange to trace color changing 
    onChangeCss: function(value){
    }
});

return ColorPalette;   });
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, the way to extend a dojo dijit is something like the following:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/ColorPalette'
], function(declare, ColorPalette) {

return declare([ColorPalette], {
    // add additonal functionality here
});});
```

After a quick look at `dijit/ColorPalette` and `dijit/_PaletteMixin`, you could extend `dijit/ColorPalette` and either create a new palette array in `_palettes` that includes a transparent color or extend the 7x10 or 3x4 palette that you're using. You'll also probably have to override the `dyeClass` attribute with a class that can return a distinct value for no color.

However, if I were doing this, I would go with something like your option 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Trying to extend `dijit/ColorPalette` I faced with some problems. Biggest of them _(for me)_ is that the palette operates especially hex values of colors _(it does not support alpha channel even if i override color table with `transparent` [implemented here](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/13370))_ and supporting of standard color table names are coded deeper than I expected. These make it complicated for me. 
**I will try another option**
Any way I'm appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to subclass `dijit/ColorPalette` (as in [Thomas Upton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54378/thomas-upton)'s answer), you can use [dojo/_base/lang::extend](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#extend) to add functionality and properties to the `ColorPalette` "class."

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/ColorPalette"], function(lang, ColorPalette) {

    /* Extends the ColorPalette prototype */
    lang.extend(ColorPalette, { 
        newProperty: newValue
    });

});
```

Doing this will give **all** future instance of `dijit/ColorPalette` the property, `newProperty`. If you only want to apply this to a **single** instance, use [dojo/_base_lang::mixin](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-mixin) instance.

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/ColorPalette"], function(lang, ColorPalette) {

    var cp = new ColorPalette({ /* properties */ });

    /* Mixes the second object __into__ the first object. */
    lang.mixin(cp, { 
        newProperty: newValue;
    });
}
```